# Chong inequalites about permutations

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, inequality

I read about two inequalities called Chong's inequalities. They state:
$$\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{a_k}{a_{\pi(k)}}\ge N$$
and
$$\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^Na_k^{a_k}\ge\prod_{k=1}^N a_k^{a_{\pi(k)}}$$
I suppose in the two inequalities $\pi(k)$ refers to the permutations of $k$. What $\pi(k)$ means exatly in this case? Is there some reference to the proof of this theorem? Thanks.

Comment: The inequalities hold for any permutation $\pi$. See Quang Hoang's answer for a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes $\pi(k)$ denotes permutations. The two inequalities are just simple applications of the Rearrangement Inequality (pls search wiki for it).